# Does For Each acting on a List always visit elements in the same order?

Tags: vb.net, list, foreach

Will the elements in `myList` always be visited in the same order with a `For Each` loop (assuming I don't alter the list)?

```
Dim myList As New List(Of MyElement)

....

For Each myElem As MyElement In myList

    ' yadda yadda yadda

Next
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they will always be in the natural list order.

`For Each` is basically a language constructor around calling `GetEnumerator()`/`MoveNext()`/`Current`, so the ordering is up to the `List(Of T)` class - which does indeed preserve ordering.

To give a contrasting example, if you iterate over the key/value pairs in a `Dictionary(Of TKey, Of TValue)` then the order *isn't* guaranteed and adding or removing one entry is allowed to change the entire ordering.